# Regex para adicionar um nível de hierarquia em todas as regras CSS

Tags: css, regex

Não tenho muito conhecimento sobre regex (acho que ninguém entende completamente isso) e gostaria de fazer uma expressão regular para alterar um arquivo CSS colocando um nível de hierarquia(uma classe chamada "minhaClasse" por exemplo) em todas as regras, da seguinte maneira:

Código atual

```
div {
   width: 100%;
   border: 5px solid #F00;
}

.botao-vermelho {
   background: #F00;
}

div .botao-vermelho {
   color: #000;
}
```

Código desejado

```
.minhaClasse div {
   width: 100%;
   border: 5px solid #F00;
}

.minhaClasse .botao-vermelho {
   background: #F00;
}

.minhaClasse div .botao-vermelho {
   color: #000;
}
```

o arquivo css é bem extenso e não é viável fazer isso na mão

Comment: Pesquisa por LESS ou SASS. Esquece isso aí que você está falando. Conselho: esquece.

Comment: @PeterParker ué se for só uma ediçãozinha não tem problema. Editar arquivos com regex é uma habilidade sempre útil.

Comment: O mais importante que tem que entender sobre RegEx é que o nome não é à toa: "expressões **regulares**". Na maioria dos casos onde é bem usada,só foi usada por não ter jeito mais simples com operações de string. Para coisas repetitivas, o RegEx pode ser uma boa, pois aí você não perde o overhead da compilação à toa. Em compensação, aqui no SOpt eu vejo usada em excesso em coisas que não são caso pra RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern que você está procurando é

```
(.+) {
```

Substitua por

```
.minhaClasse \1 {
```

Comment: Eu precisei por uma / antes da { no Find&Replace do Sublime, mas funcionou certinho, obrigado!